# Jest not found while running JEST in docker container

Tags: node.js, docker, jestjs

I have created below simple Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:16.7.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN npm install
# ENTRYPOINT [ "npm" ]
CMD ["sh", "-c", "tail -f /dev/null"]
```

I have added a cmd line with `"tail -f /dev/null"` to check exactly what's the issue if I issue `npm test` inside the container.

As soon as I run `npm test` inside the container --> It throws me below error

```
# npm test

> docker-jest@1.0.0 test
> jest --verbose

sh: 1: jest: not found
```

my `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "docker-jest",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Package for Jest",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest --verbose"
  },
  "Dependencies": {
    "@babel/node": "*",
    "@babel/core": "*",
    "@babel/preset-env": "*",
    "babel-jest": "*",
    "jest": "*"
  },
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

sum.js

```
function sum(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}

module.exports = sum;
```

sum.test.js

```
const sum = require('./sum');

test('adds 1 + 2 to equal 3', () => {
  expect(sum(1, 2)).toBe(3);
});
```

Even if I disable CMD and enable ENTRYPOINT and after the build, if I issue:

```
docker run -it <imagename> test
```

It throws me the same error, I see the `npm install` is installing but can't find the jest @ `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/` as I see the node modules are deployed in location`/usr/local/lib/node_modules/` inside the container, and if I issue `jest` it says `jest not found`. If I, run the same without the container it works fine. I mean just in the command line after running `npm install and then npm run test`.

Can anyone assist me with why I'm getting this error and how to fix it?

-----------UPDATE-------------
`Found the fix`, it was because of my corrupted package-lock file. When I tested in local without the docker, I somehow corrupted the lock file, and later stage when I build and try to run using docker, the corrupted lock file was causing a whole lot of issues. So I deleted it and again ran thru docker...It's working as expected.

Comment: for me it worked well, are you sure you build & run the proper image ID? as everything works fine for me

Docker version 20.10.8, build 3967b7d

Comment: It's strange the same is working for you while for me it's not and yes, I checked and all are the same. another strange is if I run `npm install -g jest` inside the container, then I can able to run jest. apart from npm install during the docker build command. Now I'm not sure if you can run `global` packages in your normal package.json.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue and the fix for me was running npm install -g jest (or yarn global add jest).

To add this to your package.json do the following:

```
"scripts: {
  "test": "npm install -g jest && jest --verbose"
},
```